# Error: "Dashboard" is not a valid value for --theme

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have attempted a few times to create my own bake theme following the tutorial here:
https://book.cakephp.org/bake/1/en/development.html#creating-a-bake-theme

When I attempt to run my theme, called Dashboard, I get these:

```
Error: "Dashboard" is not a valid value for --theme. Please use one of "Bake, Migrations, WyriHaximus/TwigView"
Error: "DashboardTheme" is not a valid value for --theme. Please use one of "Bake, Migrations, WyriHaximus/TwigView"
```

I attempted the following commands:

```
cake bake all --theme Dashboard clients
cake bake all --theme DashboardTheme clients
```

My file structure:

[image]

Comment: Maybe your plugin isn't loaded, check `cake plugin loaded`.

Comment: This was it. I was sure it was loaded, but it wasn't. Much time wasted. Thanks. Feel free to submit an answer so that I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin wasn't loaded, missing statement in `bootstrap()`.